# Cannot display image from storage directory using vue.js in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm saving image in Storage folder path is like:

```
storage\app\public\img\images_01.png
```

now in my vue component i'm getting image like this:

this is returning following path :

```
 /storage/img/images_01.png
```

but the issue is image does not gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access files in your public folder. But you can add a symbolic link with `php artisan storage:link` so you can access what's in storage/app/public

Comment: I'm getting this error in console: GET http://localhost:8000/storage/img/images_01.png net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Do you have an add blocking browser extension installed? Maybe look here https://love2dev.com/blog/what-the-heck-does-neterr_blocked_by_client-mean-and-how-can-you-fix-it/

Comment: Yes i have ad blocker installed